# Prevent user download Videos from my web site

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I make a new web application and I'll display more videos on it, but I need to prevent the users from downloading these videos by the browser or any download program.
Is there a way to do this by java script, JQuery, C# or asp.net?

Comment: Someone can easily just view the source and take the video URL from it.

Comment: In a word, no. If they can view it, they can save it. The question is how difficult you want to make it for the users? (And the question itself is off-topic for this site)

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Delete the videos or make them not accessible via HTTP at all. If you want to "prevent downloading by the browser" this also means preventing your site from playing it.

On a more serious point: You can just make it harder. But people WILL circumvent it if they want to and most likely tools like JDownloader WILL have a plugin that does it for them eventually if your site becomes popular enough.

When using flash to play them I think there are some ways to make it harder by using RTMP and tieing it to the SWF used to play it on your site. But even for that there are tools available to circumvent it. And you'd need a proprietary (and most likely expensive) flash streaming server..

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to allow the user to watch a video via your site but prevent them from downloading it.